# Dimension value error to load model with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to denoise an image with a pre-trained model I loaded as "model". I am getting an error as a result of the dimensions being different. Here is the code I have:

```
path_clean = r"clean.png"
clean = load_img(path_clean)
path_noisy = r"noise.png"
noisy = load_img(path_noisy)
model.compile(

  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-4),
  loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error])

history = model.fit(img_to_array(noisy), img_to_array(clean), epochs=50)
```

Here is the error I get, calling from the "history" line:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "concatenate" (type Concatenate).

Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 113 and 114. Shapes are [?,113,1] and [?,114,2]. for '{{node model/concatenate/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model/conv2d_6/Relu, model/up_sampling2d/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor, model/concatenate/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,113,1,128], [?,114,2,128], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <3>.

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 113, 1, 128), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 114, 2, 128), dtype=float32)']
```

What does it mean that one is 113 and one is 114? When I print the shapes of each image using this:

```
print(img_to_array(clean).shape)
print(img_to_array(noisy).shape)
```

I get this:

```
(500, 500, 3)
(500, 500, 3)
```

So the dimensions should be the same, right? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with a certain layer within the network not managing to align the inputs that you give it. The number you see are different because the input data undergoes a series of transformations and then it arrives at this layer and everything breaks down.

Try reading the documentation for this pre-trained model to understand what its constraints are - maybe it performs some reshaping magic and expects a certain shape as input.

When you load the model, you should also be able to inspect the graph structure to understand what happens to the input up until this concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your model relies on a certain image input size (e.g., most likely a multiple of 32). So make sure that the input width and height of the images are divisible by 32.